# Rest params type for [object,prop,val][]

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters, tuples

Consider the following working function:

```
function props<
    T extends any,
    P extends keyof T,
    V extends T[P]
>(t:T,p:P,v:V){
    //...
}

props([],"length",1)
props([],"lengt",1)    // error
props([],"length","1") // error
```

How could I write this to accept a collection of tuples, e.g.

```
props(
   [[],"length",1],
   [[],"length",10],
   [[],"length","1"] // error
)
```

Without resorting to making props a kind of type-checking passthrough function like so:

```
multiProps(
   props([],"length",1),
   props([],"lengt",1),   
   props([],"length","1")
)
```

So far I've been able to write a function that accepts tuples of the form `[object,"prop"]` but have been unable to have it accept tuples with the third item (the value).

Partial solution:

```
function props<A extends any[]>
(...tuples:[...{
    [K in keyof A]:[
        A[K],
        keyof A[K],
        // ???
    ]
}]
){
   //...
}


props(
    [[],"length"],
    [{a:1},"a"],
    [{b:2},"a"] // error.
)
```

Comment: Aside: The compiler doesn't infer literal types at properties in object literals (including arrays), but you can enable this by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on an object. To the details in your question: it's not clear (to me, at least) what your expectations are. Can you edit your question to provide greater clarity?

Comment: Afraid I don't follow your point on 'doesn't infer literal types'... but I have tried to clarify the question and desired goal.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now I’m even more sure that my initial hunch was correct. Did you read the documentation at the link I shared? If so, what part(s) didn’t you understand that still leave you confused?

Comment: I'm not confused by the content at the link — even specifying `const` for each argument passed to the function, the function's type still needs to indicate that the third index has a type matching the property of the object, such that including something like `[{a:1},"a","ok"]` produces an error... I've tried to clarify the question further.

Comment: (I'd be pleased to be informed otherwise, but) I don't think the compiler can/will simultaneously _infer from_ and _allow constraining_ arguments. AFAIK, the only solution here (other than using what you called a "passthrough function" on each arg) is: to provide every object type at the first element of each tuple arg as a member in a tuple generic type parameter to the function (and create a mapped type from that to constrain the tuple args). However, at that point (IMO), it seems **much** more ergonomic to just the "passthrough function" approach.

Comment: I'm also just personally curious: are you employing this pattern in some practical application, or is it simply your own TS exploration/learning?

Comment: Here's a quick example of what I described in the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188300/rest-params-type-for-object-prop-val?noredirect=1#comment129260675_73188300): https://tsplay.dev/mLqEKW

Comment: Really appreciate the thinking (!) but Ahmed Lazhar's got the right of it. To answer your question about context, I need to pass along chunks of prop listeners for a MobX driven system where the final param in the tuples is _actually_ a handler that receives values of the type of the observable property it'll be responding to. I've simplified that last bit in the question. (If I know how to get the right type for the property, I can do the rest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array type to represent the list of the type parameters

```
function props<
    T extends any[],
    P extends {[k in keyof T]: keyof T[k]},
    V extends {[k in keyof T]: T[k][P[k]]}
>(...args: {[k in keyof T]: [t:T[k],p:P[k],v:V[k]]}){
    //...
}

props(
    [[],"length", 0],
    [{a:1},"a", 1],
    [{b:2},"a", 3] // error.
)
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, bingo — I had tried to figure out how to create typed arrays for P and V and didn't think to use the keys from T[] explicitly as the keys for those other arrays.